# Location of Rancher/kubernetes rotated certificates

Tags: kubernetes, rotation, certificate, rancher

Upgraded an RKE 0.1.9 cluster of Kubernetes 1.11.1 and Rancher 2.0.8 to latest versions. Also also done to rotate certificates from yearly to 10 years.
Cluster all upgraded OK RKE, Rancher and kubernetes all latest stable versions.
Certificates claim to have rotated OK and I can see them in /etc/kubernetes/ssl with 10 year lifetimes.
However, /etc/kubernetes/.tmp still contains old certificates and so do secrets in UI.
Can I just copy the certs from ssl to .tmp ?
Will they then get picked up automatically in UI ?

Answer (score 0):

According official documentation (https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/cluster-admin/certificate-rotation):

> If you are upgrading from Rancher v2.0.13 or earlier, or v2.1.8 or
> earlier, and your clusters have expired certificates, some manual
> steps are required to complete the certificate rotation.
>
> ```
> cp -r /etc/kubernetes/ssl /etc/kubernetes/.tmp
> ```